# Why Lockhart, Dar Adal and the third guy did this in Homeland

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

At the end of the third season

> Brody is hanged.
>  It was approved by Dar Adal, Lockhart, and some other guy according to them on the presidential command.

But it seems unnecessary since Brody and Carrie were already in the safe house. It seems that the hard part of escape was done already. They even planned the future together like everything is fine. The rescue action was initiated already. What were the risks for the C.I.A or USA?

Put simply: **Why they did it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Brody#Season_3):

> While thinking a CIA extraction team was on the way, Javadi's men arrive and take Brody into custody, **part of a deal the CIA made with Javadi to help him advance to greater power within the Iranian government**. Brody is found guilty of being an enemy of the State, and sentenced to death. Carrie calls him in his cell to reassure him that she will save him, but he replies that he has accepted his fate and just wants it to be over. The next morning, Brody is hanged in a public square as Carrie tearfully looks on.

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer even though I don't think it is very logical (in universe).